# Is it possible to change the default "symbol template" for layers added to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

Can QGIS be configured so that the fill symbols of layers added to the map automatically have a transparent border?  I'm calling it a "symbol template" because I don't know what that's called in QGIS-world.

I would like to set the border to transparent, but keep the random fill color (or however QGIS is choosing the next color) for all layers added to the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can (in 2.12 anyway), although you need to do it for each project individually.

Go to Project -> Project Properties -> Default Styles.  You can then select one of the in-built styles for fill and then edit it to set a transparent border.  To maintain random colouring ensure that the 'assign random colors to symbols' checkbox is ticked.

I've tried it by adding half a dozen memory layers and it seems too work.

[image]

Comment: +1 and ✔. That worked perfectly!  I opened that dialog, but didn't think I was in the correct place.  I was missing the `Assign random colors to symbols` checkbox on the previous dialog.